# Expo - Firebase Email Verification

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

Im try to send a verification email to the user when he creates his account. Currently it works when Im running it on the expo app in development mode, but when I build the app there is no email sent from firebase

This is the code which sends the verification.

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
user.sendEmailVerification().then(() => {
     navigation.navigate("Main")
}).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err)
})
```

Im using managed workflow
SDK 41

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded my SDK from 40 to 41, since over the air updates don't work when you have changed the SDK (you need to download the update from the App Store).
After manually updated the app, the email verification works